# Calling a javascript function in a define block from a different function in the block

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

The following is a simplified version of my code.

```
define ([ 
"dojo/dom",
"dojo/_base/array", 
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dgrid/OnDemandGrid", 
"dgrid/Selection",
"dgrid/Keyboard",
"dijit/form/Button",
"dojo/store/Memory",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojo/string",
"esri/layers/FeatureLayer", 
"esri/tasks/query",
"esri/tasks/QueryTask",
"javascript/myUtilities",
"javascript/myCSV",
"javascript/myGrid"
  ], function (  
dom,arrayUtils,declare,Grid,Selection,Keyboard,Button,Memory,domConstruct,dojoString,FeatureLayer,Query,QueryTask, myUtilities, myCSV, myGrid) {  
return {
        initializeParkGrid: function(gridid, gridDiv){
                            //code is here
                            return app.parkGrid;
                            },     
        initializeTrailGrid: function(gridid, gridDiv){
                                //code is here
                            return app.trailGrid;
                            },

        updateParkGrid: function(){     
                                //code is here

                              app.parkGrid.on('.dgrid-row:click', function(event){
                                  initializeTrailGrid();
                              });
                            });
                        }                                   
        };
  });
```

I want to call the `initializeTrailGrid()` function whenever a row is clicked in the `app.parkGrid`.   When I try to run it as it is written I get an error telling me `initializeTrailGrid` is not a function.  If I call `initializeTrailGrid()` from a `define` block in a different file it works fine.  The code shown above is in the file `myGrid` so I tried putting `javascript/myGrid` in the define list and using `myGrid.initializeTrailGrid()` to call it but that didn't work either.  Is there a way to do this given how the `define` block is structured?

Comment: You need to import it.

Comment: My javascript skills are limited.  What do you mean by importing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's better to create a class:

```
Myclass = function () {
    this.initializeParkGrid = function (gridid, gridDiv) {
        return app.parkGrid;
    }
}
```

then, on click event, call method... don't forget to initialize the class:

```
var myclass = new Myclass();

app.parkGrid.on('.dgrid-row:click', function(event){
   myclass.initializeParkGrid(a, b);
});
```